# How to use JW Player Video Module, To Stream Video Intelligently, w/ bitrate switching. Is it possible?

Tags: 7, media

I'm not a developer, so excuse any terminological or module reference errors, but as I understand things, the title sums up our primary obstacle. We can store video files on AmazonS3 and distribute via CloudFront etc. and access a single streamed video file. However, how does one set things up so that JW Player (through Drupal) can intelligently serve differently encoded video files (of the same underlying video file content), based on end user system/bandwidth conditions/constraints, as per the benefits of RTMP or http-pseudo streaming or some other analogous approach (i.e. make the setup handle bitrate switching)?

As I understand it, there are no obvious 'exposure points' within the JW Player Module for Drupal that would allow us to do this.

Is this possible and, if so, any pointers? We're totally lost at this point, and would immensely appreciate some help....

Alternatively, how does one use the HD 'plugin' through the Drupal JW Player Module approach, to 'display' an HD 'option' overlay, thus allowing the end user to 'select' his/her own video quality preference? We don't see how.

Yet a 3rd, and least desirable, option would be to upload two differently encoded videos, one using a preset for lowest common denominator usage and the other for HD - and then simply label them accordingly. In essence have duplicate files for everything, labelled SD and HD...Not elegant.